# How to get previous month data when we click on current month bar?

Tags: spotfire

How to get previous month data when we click on current month bar?

When I click on the first chart (above) the drill down chart (bottom) should provide me the previous month data, for eg if I click on March the drill down chart should give me February data.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a second data table that mirrors your current data set, but add a column with the previous month. Use that column to create a relationship between your initial data set and the mirrored data set, and then configure your details visualization to use the second data set.

Alternately, you can create a data function which generates the second data table on the fly--this is more complicated, but the approach I'd recommend if you've got data sets large enough that you don't want to replicate them.